# Remove Antarctica from World time zone map AmCharts v4

Tags: amcharts

Is it possible to remove antarctica from this map ?
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/world-time-zone-map/

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude Antartica's code in your `polygonSeries`

```
polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
```